# hardened wordpress linux install

Tags: themes, security, installation, configuration

Are there any best practices for wordpress hardened install on Linux? I have recently had a WAMP server get malware attacked via word press so I want to harden the server up using read only apache permissions and move them and all future wordpress sites to Linux only

the plan:

1. chown everything root:root -R so that apache can't write to anything
2. chmod so that only owner can write
3. chown only the uploads / updated files/ themes/ dirs of wordpress to apache: root

this last bit is the bit I need help on, can you tell me which bits of auto-updatedness wordpress is likely to need? I have looked online and no-one is talking about this.

Comment: downgrade? are you serious? WordPress is a liability 3rd party application and you downgrade me trying to mitigate it? It's either this or I have to ban word press from my servers

Comment: This belongs on serverfault or stackoverflow.

Comment: It is very broad but is a ["server configuration for WordPress"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question. I think it is on topic.

Comment: @Whyk why? - it's not a server installation question nor a programming question

Answer (score 2):

**Heavily edited from the above link**

**How to Harden your Word Press if you're a server admin**

Bear in mind I am not an expert on Word Press nor even a user of it: you will probably not be able to automatically self update word press (which is by default a *massive* security issue since vulnerabilities today are published in the future by the open source community and easily viewable/used in the future) by using this method and your may or may not be able to install/update plugins and you will not be able to do this at all on Windows Servers.

```
/ 
The root WordPress directory:
```

all files should be writeable only by `your user account (*not Apache*)`, except .htaccess if you want WordPress to automatically generate rewrite rules for you.

```
/wp-admin/ 
The WordPress administration area:
```

all files should be writeable only by `your user account (*not Apache*)`.

```
/wp-includes/ 
The bulk of WordPress application logic:
```

all files should be writeable only by `your user account (*not Apache*)`.

```
/wp-content/ 
User-supplied content:
```

intended to be writeable by `your user account AND Apache`.

Within /wp-content/ you will find:

```
/wp-content/themes/ 
Theme files.
```

If you want to use the built-in theme editor, all files need to be writeable by `the web server process (Apache)`. If you do not want to use the built-in theme editor, all files can be writeable only by `your user account (*not Apache*)`.

```
/wp-content/plugins/ 
Plugin files:
```

all files should be writeable only by `your user account (*Not Apache*)`.

**so the ACTUAL answer on CENTOS is:**

do the following substituting mywordpressplace for your word press installation directory, do the commands as `root` and use `root` too if you like it won't matter, the books say you should do the following shell commands in `root` and then use a `3rd party user` as the user in the command line entries below but I think that if you have multiple servers (I have around 40 that I run) and if you have hardened infrastructure it's probably satisfactory to merely use `root` for both - so long as you have ssh correctly configured etc etc

```
# chown -R root:root /var/www/html/mywordpressplace/
# chmod -R 744  /var/www/html/mywordpressplace/
# chown -R apache:root /var/www/html/mywordpressplace/.htaccess
# chown apache:root /var/www/html/mywordpressplace/wp-content/ 
# chown -R apache:root /var/www/html/mywordpressplace/wp-content/themes/
# chown -R apache:root /var/www/html/mywordpressplace/wp-content/plugins/
```

*one last gotcha*

the last bit is important - since the wordpress malware that can and does exist often uses php to read/write/traverse your directory to insert code and since apache must be able to read the /var/www/html/ dir you also need to ensure that anything ELSE on that server in /var/www/html/ must ALSO be

```
# chown -R root:root /var/www/html/*
```

What happens is that WordPress malware will traverse the web root dir and inject code (curl() commands usually) into *any* index.php/default.php files from OTHER sites that are NON word press at all. Wordpress can often be the vector for other sites on the vhost

Answer (score 1):

> ... can you tell me which bits of auto-updatedness wordpress is likely to need?

WordPress doesn't ***need*** any "auto-updatedness". Auto-updating is just a convenience. In fact, the built-in updater is a relatively new thing, though I don't remember at what version it appeared. You can always [update manually](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update) via (s)FTP and I pretty much always do.

> I have looked online and no-one is talking about this

No one is talking about what?

https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/

Comment: I still say no-one is looking at this properly that was a lot of `TLDR` about concept based stuff and not even examples of commands for admins just a general principles guide with some dig yourself to finish

Comment: "TLDR"? "Too long didn't read"? Seriously?

Comment: .. it is lengthy there are there 28 headings, most (almost all) are actually `good policy` chit-chat,  or intro-ing of concepts and a general mixing from a non-wp-server-admin/non-admin-user point of view with a  bias to the latter (EG: config specifics, rewrite rules etc, asusing .htaccess only)